# найти число в строке

Tags: c++, строки, поиск, числа

есть string строка, например

```
string str ="ddadsadwd 1337 dsdggf";
```

нужно найти в ней число и выписать в переменную int

Comment: Идёте по строке до первой цифры. Это предполагаемое начало числа, идёте дальше до пробела или конца строки - это конец записи числа.

Comment: @АлексейСаровский можете написать в виде кода? Или какие функции можно использовать

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/ Дальше расписывать - совсем неспортивно.

Comment: @PinkTux я немного не понял, я найду начало числа,но как записать его в переменную?

Comment: А чуть дальше документацию полистать по стандартной библиотеке - не?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(void)
{
    std::string s ="ddadsadwd 1337 dsdggf";
    size_t digits = s.find_first_of( "1234567890+-" );
    if( digits <= s.size() ) {
        std::cout << "Number found: " << atoi( s.c_str() + digits ) << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Number is not found" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Имеется несколько способов решения поставленной задачи. Один из прямолинейных способов может выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() 
{
    std::string str ="ddadsadwd 1337 dsdggf";
    int n = 0;

    auto it = std::find_if( str.begin(), str.end(), isdigit );

    if ( it != str.end() ) n = std::atoi( str.c_str() + ( it - str.begin() ) );

    std::cout << n << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
1337
```

При этом предполагается, что число в строке не содержит знак. Иначе вам придется использовать другой предикат в алгоритме `std::find_if`, который также будет делать проверку на знак числа.

Comment: пишет it does not name a type

Comment: @topl3niy В каком предложении возникает эта ошибка?

Comment: там где вы инициализируете auto it

Comment: @topl3niy Код должен успешно компилироваться, если вы его скопировали без ошибок. Вы также можете заменить auto it на std::string::iterator it

Comment: @topl3niy наверное, имеет смысл использовать c++11 в 2016 году (флажок --std==c++11)

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с `regex`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s = "ddadsadwd 1337 dsdggf";
    regex p("\\d+");
    regex_token_iterator<string::iterator> numbers( s.begin(), s.end(), p );
    string t = *numbers;
    int first_number = atoi( t.c_str() );
    cout << first_number << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. Почему не работает `(*numbers).c_str()`?